# Calc in a function with the values of a pointer - in C

Tags: c

Hey guys I am trying to make a calculator mainly I want to do that with pointer and functions,
so first I am running a switch case that the user can choose the operation, than it has to jump in the following function where the operation is written down.

My most troubleshooting problem is that I pass the values by a pointer throw the switch case in the calculation operation - but in the end I reconized that isn't possible to calc with pointers.

So i am asking is there any way to calc with the values of the pointers?
Or did I think to difficult?
I also thought about making the function as a function pointer but I didn't got the systematic behind that yet...
Maybe u have a better Idea, I will be open minded.

```
float numOne = 0;
float numTwo = 0;
float solution = 0;

int numExist = 0; //If numExist is 0, than num didnt Exist
int op = 0; //Calculation operation

void calc(int *op, int *numExist, float *numOne, float *numTwo, float *solution){
        switch(*op)
            {
            case 1: addition(numExist, numOne, numTwo, solution); break;
    
            }
    }
    
    void addition(int *numExist, float *numOne, float *numTwo, float *solution){
    //numOne+numTwo=*solution;thats what I am looking for
    }

int main(){
calc(&op, &numExist, &numOne, &numTwo, &solution);
}
```

Thanks in forward for any help tips and tricks.

Comment: what why where? why would you even pass these as pointers? Simple fix: do not use **any** pointers at all and let **calc** and the operations return the result of the operation.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too, that could be the easiest way. But in my training task it is mentioned that I have to use call by reference.

Comment: `*solution = *numOne + *numTwo;` Though I think there is a possibility you may have misunderstood the original requirements. Maybe `solution` should be a pointer but not the other values.

Comment: If its all numeric types, why use pointers at all? Even for the `solution`. Its pretty easy to have numeric args and return numeric results from functions -- so take advantage of that privilege.

Answer (score 1):

Make your code look like this:

```
float numOne = 0;
float numTwo = 0;
float solution = 0;

int numExist = 0; 
int op = 0;

void calc(int op, int numExist, float numOne, float numTwo, float *solution){
    switch(op)
    {
        case 1: addition(numExist, numOne, numTwo, solution); 
        break;
    }
}
    
void addition(int numExist, float numOne, float numTwo, float *solution)
{
    *solution = numOne + numTwo;
}

int main()
{
    op = 1;
    calc(op, numExist, numOne, numTwo, &solution);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
float numOne = 0;
float numTwo = 0;
float solution = 0;

int numExist = 0; //If numExist is 0, than num didnt Exist
int op = 0; //Calculation operation

float calc(int *op, int *numExist, float *numOne, float *numTwo, float *solution){
        switch(*op)
            {
            case 1: addition(numExist, numOne, numTwo, solution); break;
    
            }
    }
    
    float addition(int *numExist, float *numOne, float *numTwo, float *solution){
    return *solution= *numOne + *numTwo;
    }

int main(){
calc(&op, &numExist, &numOne, &numTwo, &solution);
}
```

i figured out a solution it is also possible to calc with pointers on the return value of a function